# Node.js best way to process asynchronous multiple objects

Tags: node.js

What's the best way to process asynchronous an high amount of objects, let's say calling a DB query, and avoid a stack overflow using a recursive function on the callback ?

i.e. I want to send 1000 queries consecutive to a DB...

thanks

Comment: There isn't near enough information in this question to answer it and it appears you don't have anything specific. This topic, in its current form, would be too large for this forum.

Comment: what else should I ask ? Let's say I want to collect the status of 1000 users from a supplied user id from json....I simply cannot use a for() loop neither a simple callback after each query is done, because I'll end with a 1000 entry stack trace that will probably produce a stack overflow... so I'm asking for a solution to this....

Comment: The issue stems from the fact that you need to better understand Node at its core and how it works. How requests are handled and how external resources are too. The stack your talking about could be implemented many different ways but that would depend a lot on what dependencies you already have. It's just too broad. You need to narrow down you situation or you need to spend some time really diving into Node and getting an understanding of the engine. That would likely answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: is asking how to send 1000 queries on an array too generic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone with the same problem, there's a specific module for this:

https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel